# Summing the digits in Excel cells (long and short strings)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a research related to frequencies.

I want to sum all the numbers in each cell and reduce them to single number only.

some cells have 2 numbers, others have 13 numbers. like these..

```
24.0542653897891
25.4846064424057
27
28.6055035477009
```

I tried several formulas to do that. the best ones have me 2 digits number, that I couldn't sum it again to get a single result.

like these Formulas:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B5,".",""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B5)-1)),1)+0)
=SUMPRODUCT(1*MID(C5,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(C5))),1))
```

any suggestion?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe use _Text to Columns_ to split the numbers into separate cells?

Comment: Could you add desired results just for clarity?

Comment: Agree with @JvdV .. Though your comments "the best ones have me 2 digits number, that I couldn't sum it again to get a single result." and the formulas you have given make me think that you are looking for some formula to keep adding all the digits in a cell and result thereof until you get a single digit.. Otherwise, JvdV's formula is simply great. No need for VBA

Comment: @NareshBhople exactly... I need to keep adding digits till i get a single digit result...4 or 5 or 6...

Comment: The you need UDF like my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on your explanation your comments, it seems that what you want is what is called the **digital root** of the all the digits (excluding the decimal point).  In other words, repeatedly summing the digits until you get to a single **digit**.

That can be calculated by a simpler formula than adding up the digits.

```
=1+(SUBSTITUTE(B5,".","")-1)-(INT((SUBSTITUTE(B5,".","")-1)/9)*9)
```

For long numbers, we can split the number in half and process each half. eg:

```
=1+MOD(1+MOD(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B5,".",""),INT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B5,".",""))/2))-1,9)+1+MOD(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B5,".",""),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B5,".",""))-INT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B5,".",""))/2))-1,9)-1,9)
```

**However, the numbers should be stored as TEXT.**  When numbers are stored as numbers, what we see may not necessarily be what is stored there, and what the formula (as well as the UDF) will process.

The long formula version will correct all the errors on your worksheet EXCEPT for B104.  B104 appears to have the value `5226.9332653096000` but Excel is really storing the value `5226.9333265309688`. Because of Excel's precision limitations, this will get processed as `5226.93332653097`. Hence there will be a disagreement.

**Another method that should work** would be to round all of the results in your column B to 15 digits (eg: .  Combining that with using the long formula version should result in agreement for all the values you show.

*Explanation*

- if a number is divisible by 9, its digital root will be 9, otherwise, the digital root will be `n MOD 9`
- The general formula would be:  `=1+Mod(n-1,9)`

  - In your case, since we are dealing with numbers larger than can be calculated using the `MOD` function, we need to both remove the dot, and also use the equivalent of mod which is `n-(int(n/9)*9)`
- Notes:

  - this will work best with numbers stored as text. Since Excel may display and/or convert large numbers, or numbers with many decimal places, differently than expected, working with text strings of digits is the most stable method.
  - this method will not work reliably with numbers > 15 digits.

If you have numbers > 15 digits, then I suggest a VBA User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit
Function digitalRoot(num As String) As Long
    Dim S As String, Sum As Long, I As Long
S = num
Do While Len(S) > 1
    Sum = 0
    For I = 1 To Len(S)
        Sum = Sum + Val(Mid(S, I, 1))
    Next I
    S = Trim(Str(Sum))
Loop

digitalRoot = CLng(S)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, well I wanted the result to be a single digit, like instead of getting 73 i want 1 (7+3=10 = 1+0=1)

Comment: @SaherAl-Sous That can be done with an even simpler formula.  See my Edit

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks. I was uncertain about that, but I'll take your advice.

Comment: Great to learn this .. Even the UDF in my answer gives weird results if the number is more than 15 digits

Comment: @NareshBhople Process the number as a text string.

Comment: I tried your suggestion (myNumber As String) and noticed that it depends upon how the number is entered in excel sheet. If it is entered in excel sheet as number then it will run into  the scientific notation after 15 digits and then the UDF will give sum till E+ as there will be no way to convert it back to Standard notation with all digits. If the number is entered as text ( ' preceding the number) then UDF will work fine even for more than 15 digits number even if type of myNumber is not defined (or variant).. I hope I am not making mistake there....Thanks for the guidance. Needed it. :)

Comment: @NareshBhople Yes, the number definitely has to be entered onto the Excel sheet as as string, else you will be limited to Excel's numeric precision limit of about 15 digits.

Comment: Dear @RonRosenfeld, I hope that i didn't do any mistake in implementing the UDA, but what i got was #NAME?
The numbers i got are a result of a Formula that brings the number as a result.
but the equation you gave me worked as needed...
16.35159783128740 --> 7
17.32391443605450 --> 3

=1+(SUBSTITUTE(B5,".","")-1)-(INT((SUBSTITUTE(B5,".","")-1)/9)*9)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I worked on it... most of the numbers are calculated correctly... (the formula not VBA) but some results are weird, like either the result is wrong, or it is wrong and in minus... like getting -3 instead of 5+3=8....
but better than nothing... will try to fix the errors manually....
Thank you

Comment: @SaherAl-Sous #NAME? means you did something wrong. Excel cannot find the function, or an argument to the function. What number fails with formula? Was number entered as text? Is it too long?

Comment: @SaherAl-Sous For the formula issues, see the `Notes` above in my answer.  Your numbers are long, and they are numbers and not text representations.  For the UDF issue, you have given the module the same name as the function. This confuses Excel so it doesn't know what you are referring to by 'digitalRoot`, hence the `#NAME?` error.  Again, since you are not passing the numbers at text strings, but rather as unrounded numbers, the results may be unexpected.

Comment: @SaherAl-Sous Also see my latest edits for information on some workarounds for your long-number numeric-format issues.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are looking for something like following UDF.

```
Function SumToOneDigit(myNumber)
Dim temp: temp = 0
CalcLoop:

For i = 1 To Len(myNumber)
If IsNumeric(Mid(myNumber, i, 1)) Then temp = temp + Mid(myNumber, i, 1)
Next

If Len(temp) > 1 Then
myNumber = temp
temp = 0
GoTo CalcLoop
End If

SumToOneDigit = temp
End Function
```

UDF (User Defined Functions) are codes in VBA (visual basic for applications).

When you can not make calculations with Given Excel functions like ones in your question, you can UDFs in VBA module in Excel. See [this link for UDF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTPO7wttzgU) .. If you dont have developer tab see [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLQ8OuW0FlY) ,, Add a module in VBA in by right clicking on the workbook and paste the above code in that module. Remember, this code remains in this workbook only. So, if you want to use this UDF in some other file your will have to add module in that file and paste the code in there as well. If you are frequently using such an UDF, better to make add-in out of it like [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZufTYoeNqlY)

Comment: @Gary'sStudent .. Thanks .. But still not sure if this is the answer the OP is looking for :)

Comment: The OP did not include any expected results.

Comment: well, I never knew that we can write these in Excel, but What i want is that i want to sum all the digits in a cell, and get a single digit result. like 1 or 2 or 3....
if this function do this, how can i use it and implement it in the cells?

Comment: When you can not make calculations with Given Excel functions like ones in your question, you can write a code in visual basic for applications module in Excel. See [this link for UDF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTPO7wttzgU) .. If you dont have developer tab see [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLQ8OuW0FlY) ,, Add a module in VBA in by right clicking on the workbook and paste the code above in that module. Remember, this code remains in this workbook only.

Comment: I will check this on my PC (Currently on mac) to install VBA and do it. will keep you posted... thank you so much

Comment: WHy install VBA cant you access developer tab as mentioned above? .. See [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZ4xTecAxZ4) .. also edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use a formula like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

You might need an extra `SUBSTITUTE` for changing `.` to `,` if that's your decimal delimiter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",",")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

However, maybe a UDF as others proposed is also a possibility for you. Though, something tells me I might have misinterpreted your question...

Comment: thank you for your response, well I wanted the result to be a single digit, like instead of getting 73 i want 1 (7+3=10 = 1+0=1)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using "Text to Columns" as a one-off conversion, this is relatively easy to do in VBA, by creating a user function that accepts the data as a string, splits it into an array separated by spaces, and then loops the elements to add them up.

Add the following VBA code to a new module:

```
Function fSumData(strData As String) As Double
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim aData() As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    aData = Split(strData, " ")
    For lngLoop1 = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        fSumData = fSumData + CDbl(aData(lngLoop1))
    Next lngLoop1
fExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "fSumData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume fExit
End Function
```

Then enter this into a cell in the Excel worksheet:

```
=fSumData(A1)
```

Regards,

Comment: Pretty sure the error message box won't display when used as a worksheet function.  Use `CVERR` instead - replace the `MsgBox` line with `fSumData = CVERR(xlErrNum)` and change the function to return a `Variant` rather than a `Double` - this will then return `#NUM!` if the function fails.

Comment: The `MsgBox` does appear when you use it as a Worksheet function. It depends whether you want to use this as a Worksheet only function, or have the ability to use this additionally within other VBA functions.

Comment: VBA = Visual Basic?
I have excel on mac, do i have that in default?
how can i use it?
I suppose that this function adds all the numbers into the cell and get a single digit result at the end right?

Answer (score 1):

The UDF below will return the sum of all numbers in a cell passed to it as an argument.

```
Function SumCell(Cell As Range) As Double

    Dim Fun     As Double           ' function return value
    Dim Sp()    As String           ' helper array
    Dim i       As Integer          ' index to helper array

    Sp = Split(Cell.Cells(1).Value)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
        Fun = Fun + Val(Sp(i))
    Next i

    SumCell = Fun
End Function
```

Install the function in a standard code module, created with a name like `Module1`. Call it from the worksheet with syntax like `=SumCell(A2)` where A2 is the cell that contains the numbers to be summed up. Copy down as you would a built-in function.

Comment: does excel on mac have UDF?

Comment: Why don't you try and let us know?